# Node Express Consolidate Hogan - Inconsistent error when compiling partials

Tags: node.js, express, hogan.js

I updated my application from older libs to the newest one but I encounter an inconsistent error.
My libs :

```
npm list --depth=0
    ├── consolidate@0.10.0
    ├── express@4.4.4
    ├── hogan.js@3.0.2
    ├── node-uuid@1.4.1
    └── socket.io@1.0.6
```

Here is a sample of the code I run. Full code [here](https://github.com/Philaeux/dota2draft).

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var uuid = require('node-uuid');
var consolidate = require('consolidate');

//////////////////////
// Server setup
//////////////////////
var app = express();
app.engine('html', consolidate.hogan);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.enable('view cache');
app.disable('view layout');

var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
io.set('log level', 1); // reduce logging

server.listen(9000);

//////////////////////
// Routing
//////////////////////
// Partials used in many rendering views
function hoganPartials() {
    return {
        head : 'common/head',
        mainHeader : 'common/mainHeader',
        mainFooter : 'common/mainFooter'
    };
};

app.use('/files', express.static(__dirname + '/files'));

app.get('/about', function(req, res) {
    res.render('about', {
        partials: hoganPartials(),
        title : 'Title - About'
    });
});
```

So when I run this code, I have *sometimes* a random error:

- If the page first renders correctly, it will always render correctly, even after refresh.
- If the page fails to render with *error1*, every time I will refresh, it will fail to render with *error2*.
- Some view may render, and other not, even if they share the same partials.
- Restarting the application will reset errors and some view failing on the previous run may work in the current one and vice versa.
- Disabling view caching has no impact.

**Error 1**

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( at Object.Function (<anonymous>) 
    at Object.Hogan.makePartials (/home/philaeux/dota2draft/node_modules/hogan.js/lib/compiler.js:301:28) 
    at Object.Hogan.makeTemplate (/home/philaeux/dota2draft/node_modules/hogan.js/lib/compiler.js:290:25) 
    at Object.Hogan.generate (/home/philaeux/dota2draft/node_modules/hogan.js/lib/compiler.js:280:17) 
    at Object.Hogan.compile (/home/philaeux/dota2draft/node_modules/hogan.js/lib/compiler.js:416:21) 
    at Function.exports.hogan.render (/home/philaeux/dota2draft/node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:448:56) 
    at /home/philaeux/dota2draft/node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:144:25 
    at /home/philaeux/dota2draft/node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:97:5 
    at fs.js:271:14 
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

**Error 2**

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( at Object.Function (<anonymous>) 
    at Object.Hogan.makePartials (/home/philaeux/dota2draft/node_modules/hogan.js/lib/compiler.js:301:28) 
    at Object.Hogan.makeTemplate (/home/philaeux/dota2draft/node_modules/hogan.js/lib/compiler.js:290:25) 
    at Object.Hogan.generate (/home/philaeux/dota2draft/node_modules/hogan.js/lib/compiler.js:280:17) 
    at Object.Hogan.compile (/home/philaeux/dota2draft/node_modules/hogan.js/lib/compiler.js:416:21) 
    at Function.exports.hogan.render (/home/philaeux/dota2draft/node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:448:56) 
    at /home/philaeux/dota2draft/node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:144:25 
    at read (/home/philaeux/dota2draft/node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:91:22) 
    at /home/philaeux/dota2draft/node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:142:9 
    at next (/home/philaeux/dota2draft/node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:117:38)
```

I tried to downgrade some libs with no success. I can't remember which version I was starting from (probably express < 4.0.0). I am totally lost on this one...
Thanks for your time.

Comment: If someone is looking for an answer, I could not figure out a way to fix the error so I have replaced the Hogan engine with Handlebars. It is working flowlessly now.